# start-sleep will freeze Register-ObjectEvent action scriptblock

Tags: powershell

```
   $EventHandlerScripBlock = {
            if (! [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($EventArgs.Data)) {
                $EventArgs.Data
            }
        }

        $ProcessStdOutEvent = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $Process -Action $EventHandlerScripBlock -EventName 'OutputDataReceived'

            $emptyStopWatch = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
            while($true)
            {
                start-sleep -s 10
                [array]$output = receive-job $ProcessStdOutEvent 
                if ($output)
                {
                    $output
                    $emptyStopWatch.Restart()
                }
                elseif ($emptyStopWatch.elapsed.TotalMilliseconds -gt $OutputCheckIntervalInMs)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I want to launch a process and read its standard output. I cannot directly read the standard output from the process by `$process.standardoutput.ReadToEnd()` because it will block and wait for the process exit.
so I need to use the async style like the upper code.
But I found that the `start-sleep -s 10` will block the `EventHandlerScripBlock` execution. If I remove `start-sleep -s 10`, does it read the output too frequently?

Comment: make a function that uses the `[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]` stuff to handle your wait. the `Start-Sleep` cmdlet _stops the entire PoSh process/thread while it sleeps_, so you will need to use a timer instead of a "put powershell to sleep" technique.

Comment: thanks for your reply, if we don't "put powershell to sleep", which state should poweshell be for this period of time, keep busy looping?

Comment: PoSh would loop while the test is not yet met. if you wrap such a time loop around your process OR put a small wait loop IN the main loop, it should work while the wait loop is running. you will need to test to see what will work with your situation, tho.